# Rename [logicaal-constraints] to [logical-constraints]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Just a spelling error: [logicaal-constraints](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logicaal-constraints) should be [logical-constraints](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-constraints).

Comment: `[tag:]` is not supported in titles. Suggested title: *`Rename [logicaal-constraints] to [logical-constraints]`* and suggested body: *`Just a spelling mistake: [tag:logicaal] should be [tag:logical].`*

Comment: I just approved the edit to fix that.

Comment: So what's the protocol for this question then? Should you post an answer and I will accept it? There's no valid "close" reason so I don't think I should close it. How do I indicate that this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that only one question was tagged such; someone suggested an edit which manually removed the wrong tag and added the correct one. The tag with the typo will be automatically removed (in at most 24 hours), since it doesn't have any questions.

You don't need to close the question - we are now waiting for a moderator to mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so it will show up as completed.